# how do i get this program to write each line with a given word to a file?

Tags: python, function

i have everything working but the final step of having it write the lines to a file. any help would be awesome. i assume its either an issue with a function or a control structure thing.

```
def process(word, file_name, new_file_name):
    '''Check the file for the word and returns lines with the word in it
    '''

    file=open(file_name, 'r')
    file2=open(new_file_name, 'w')

    for line in file:
        if word in line:
               file2.write(line)    
    else:
        print("That word is not in this file.")

    file.close()
    print('File written')


def main(): 
    global line 

    word=input('Enter a word: ').strip().lower()
    file_name=input('Enter a file name: ')
    new_file_name=input('Enter a new file name: ')
    process(word, file_name, new_file_name)



main()
```

Comment: What's wrong happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close `file2`. Close that and it should be written out.

Also, a better way to open and close files is usually to use the `with` context manager:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as my_f:
    my_f.write('foo')
```

That will open and close on its own, closing outside of the `with` scope.

Also, it's more standard to write a `main` this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    # or just the main body here if it's simple enough
```

The reason for that is that you can import the file in other source code, and it won't execute main after it imports. You can write a module, import from it, or have test code in your `main` and then execute that directly to test it.

Also, what qwrrty said about your `for` `else` statement is correct. It will always print.

An `else` in a `for` or `while` loop is an interesting feature of Python that you won't see in many programming languages, for better or worse. It executes if the loop does *not* exit from a `break` statement. There is also a `try` `except` `else` that executes the `else` if the `try` block completes without any exception.

You should use an `else` for a situation like when you are iterating through a container, searching for an element, and want logic if you do not find it. If you find it, you are done, and you `break`. I don't see a good reason for an `else` in your example.

Comment: Using **w+** means *read and write*. Using **w** means *write* and if the file doesn't exist, it will create, otherwise truncating the file to 0. As the code doesn't read the contents in `file2`, whether closing the file is not related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From briefly testing this code, it appears to work as intended, and writes to `file2` all the lines from `file` that match `word`.

This code is printing a misleading message:

```
for line in file:
    if word in line:
           file2.write(line)    
else:
    print("That word is not in this file.")
```

The `else` clause to `for` is run when the iterator is exhausted, so this will always print "That word is not in this file."  You want something more like this:

```
found = False
for line in file:
    if word in line:
        file2.write(line)
        found = True

if not found:
    print("That word is not in this file.")
```

As noted, it is also a good idea to make sure that you close `file2` when you are done with it, and the `with open(...) as file2` context manager is useful for that. But that should be causing the program to misbehave in this case.